# NativeScript Google-Places API --> how to use?

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api, nativescript, search-box

I'm working on app which uses **Google-Maps-API** and i want to add `search-box` field that uses **Google-Places-API** to autocomplete what the user typed so far 
and then to save the selected item value.

https://github.com/jonny720/do-here-client

So i got my **Google-Places-API** key, and i don't really know where to put it and how to implement this API.

The  **Google-Maps-API** is placed in  the **androidMAnifest.xml** and its working fine.

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/nativescript_google_maps_api_key"
            />
```

Now Where do i actually implement the Google-Places-API and where do i need to place the key ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so this is what i did and it worked:

I build a PlacesService and this is the code :

```
autoCompleteUrl = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/xml?input=';
autoCompleteUrl2 = '&key=API_KEY'


urlReq='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/findplacefromtext/json?input=';
urlreq2 = '&inputtype=textquery&fields=formatted_address,name,geometry&key=API_KEY' 


newPlace: any;
constructor(private http :HttpClient){}

auto(typed):any{
    if (typed){
        console.log("got to func",typed)
        return this.http.get(this.autoCompleteUrl+typed+this.autoCompleteUrl2);
    } 
}


findPlace(place):any {
        // return this.http.get(this.urlReq+place+this.urlreq2);
        this.http.get(this.urlReq+place+this.urlreq2)
        .toPromise().then(res => {
            this.newPlace = JSON.stringify(res);
            console.log("#########", this.newPlace); 
        });

}
```

Now i'm getting an `JSON` object that looks like this :

```
[{"candidates":[{"formatted_address":"United States","geometry":{"location":{"lat":37.09024,"lng":-95.712891},"viewport":{"northeast":{"lat":49.38,"lng":-66.94},"southwest":{"lat":25.82,"lng":-124.39}}},"name":"United States"}],"debug_log":{"line":[]},"status":"OK"}, {"candidates":[{"formatted_address":"United States","geometry":{"location":{"lat":37.09024,"lng":-95.712891},"viewport":{"northeast":{"lat":49.38,"lng":-66.94},"southwest":{"lat":25.82,"lng":-124.39}}},"name":"United States"}],"debug_log":{"line":[]},"status":"OK"}]
```

But how do i split this Object ? i want to take only the `Name` and the `geometry` property.

thank you !

Answer (score 1):

**[Places](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-google-places-autocomplete)** and **[Maps-utils](https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/nativescript-google-maps-utils)** plugins are already available. You can use them. Did you try them?

Comment: Also, there is a [Google Maps plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-google-maps-sdk) for NativeScript.